# How to check if type is undefined in Typescript Conditional Types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have this type:

```
type ReturnType<T, E> = [T, E]
```

I 'm trying to make this type "smarter" by these rules:

- If `T` is `undefined`, then the type would be `[undefined, E]`
- If `E` is `undefined`, then the type would be `[T]`
- `T` and `E` can't **both** be `undefined`

I'm trying to apply these rules using Typescript's `Conditional Types`.
Is this even possible to implement?

This is what I got so far:

```
type ReturnType<T, E> = 
    T extends undefined 
    ? E extends undefined ? never : [undefined, E]
    : E extends undefined ? [T] : never
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is that you can do tests for both T and E at the same time with:

```
[T, E] extends [TypeA, TypeB] ? ... : ...
```

Putting that to use you can do:

```
type MyReturnType<T, E> = 
    [T, E] extends [undefined, undefined] ? never
    : T extends undefined ? [undefined, E]
    : E extends undefined ? [T]
    : [T, E]

type A = MyReturnType<undefined, undefined> // never
type B = MyReturnType<string, undefined> // [string]
type C = MyReturnType<undefined, number> // [undefined, number]
type D = MyReturnType<boolean, string> // [boolean, string]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=60#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKFgFcBOA7AKuCAeTANFAKIB8UAvFAFBR1QDahJAulBAB7AToAmAzo2R8IAMwCW6CLyLDeYydLYB+KFIBuEVLXoAuKJnZceAqHIVTeUVQ3MTLRYix119xI9z6C7iqzczO9FD6TI7O1KCQUACClLAISGhYOLg+DmYi9tLkAPQ5ahCa2pHQAEJxcIgoGNiQuPzAqJIA5rKZvrn5DA1N6M3OJVAAwhUJ1cl1adJE6MgAtgBGWp1C7emzi1oDOFAAIqNVSbV4CwD2pwA2EACG6EQ9LSsMZ5c3d1APfSxAA)